# Button to Calculate COUNTIFS in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, countif

I have the following data on the Sheet1 :

[image]

Then I've created a function to calculate each data based on specific criteria  by using the COUNTIFS function on Sheet2, here is the function :

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E8:E400,"Cash",Sheet1!J8:J400,"ADISTYARA  DEWINTHA",Sheet1!O8:O400,"Selling",Sheet1!M8:M400,"PRE SP NEW KARTU SMARTFREN 2015")
```

I want to count the number of data "SP PRE NEW CARD SMARTFREN 2015" by Adistyara Dewintha on Sheet1, then put it into a category Starter Pack on Sheet2

The above function works well and the results are as follows:

[image]

The question is, I want to create a button that when clicked the button will perform calculations on the COUNTIFS function SHEET 1 such that I created above and then the results will be inserted in the cell in Sheet2. If anyone can help, I would be very grateful and appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a working formula that provides automatic calculation, why would you relegate the operation to a button and VBA sub?

Comment: Do you mean to say you only want the function to calculate if the button has been pressed? or that you want a button to fill this formula in for the user? Or something else entirely..?

Comment: Because i've to calculate a large of amount data everyday, so if i write it manually, it's troublesome enough. I mean, every i insert a new sheet then when the button clicked it will calculate then put the result in a new cell

Comment: So you want this formula to run when you click on a button but you want it to run against a new sheet that is inserted before you click it? If so, does the old sheet get removed from the workbook before you run this calculation or does it just get added and your workbook has a large number of sheets? To me it sounds like a fairly easy solution to just write this formula in to a macro that adds it to a new cell but you need to ensure you point it to the correct sheet.

Answer (score 0):

"Because i've to calculate a large of amount data everyday, so if i write it manually, it's troublesome enough."

ok then why don't you do this

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E8:E400,A1,Sheet1!J8:J400,A2,Sheet1!O8:O400,A3,Sheet1!M8:M400,A4)
```

where

A1 = Cash

A2 =ADISTYARA  DEWINTHA

A3 = Selling

A4 = PRE SP NEW KARTU SMARTFREN 2015

or whatever value you happen to want.
this way you don't have to redo the formula just the variables.